# Как вернуть integer при вызове конструктора javascript?

Tags: javascript

Есть задача написать конструктор `A()`, который бы вернул:

```
var a = new A();

console.log(a); // 1
console.log(a); // 2
console.log(a+a); // 7
```

Мои варианты закончились. Подскажите, пожалуйста, такое вообще возможно?

Comment: Зачем вам это? Ведь конструктор возвращает объект и это его назначение. Хотите получить строку используйте строку, зачем придумывать какие-то извращения? Скажите что именно нужно, может есть более верное решение, без таких вот метаморфоз

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Вам нужно переписать методы `toString`, `valueOf` для решения задачи
JS очень неявный язык, и некоторые события происходят без нашего ведома. Например приведение типов, либо вызов каких-то методов.

В данном случае, `console.log` по умолчанию вызывает `toString` у объекта, поэтому переписав этот метод, мы можем управлять строковым отображением нашего объекта

При `a + a` неявно вызовется метод `valueOf`

Все вместе

```
function A() {
    this.int = 0;
}
A.prototype.toString = function () {
    return ++this.int;
}
A.prototype.valueOf = function () {
    return ++this.int;
}

const a = new A();
alert(a);
alert(a);
alert(a + a);
```

P.S. В последнем хроме пример с `console` не работает, возможно поменяли как-то алгоритм, с `alert-ом` все работает как нужно

Comment: Это решает задачу, но вряд ли писать такой код в проектах - правильное решение. Спасибо, принцип работы ясен.

Comment: @mix перезапись таких методов дает большие возможности для кастомизации нативных объектов и их поведений

Answer (score 1):

Это не то?

```
function A(){
    return new String("value");
}

console.log(new A());
console.log(new A().toString());
```

Comment: нет, конструктор `new A()` не возвращает строку

Comment: @min, он возвращает объект, оборачивающий в себя строку (со всеми привычными методами и прочим). По-моему, это единственный вариант.

Comment: ок. в любом случае спасибо.